# как вытащить последний элемент из списка в Scala

Tags: list, scala

дан список

```
val list = 1 :: (2 :: (3 :: Nil)) ;
```

как с помощью функции вытащить последний элемент?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```scala
list.last
```

вернёт последний элемент списка

> ТС: а как тогда вернуть предпоследний элемент?

```scala
list(list.size - 2)
```

вернёт предпоследний элемент.
В скобочках обращение к конкретному элементу, в данном случае `размер списка - 2`

Можно вынести в отдельную функцию, где обработать на возможность ошибок.
Например, возвращать `Option`, если вдруг захочется получить `-1ый элемент списка`.

Не знаю насколько корректно, но можно ещё поиграться с методом `take`

```scala
list.take(2).last //вернёт 2 из list(1, 2, 3)
```

output:

```
> 2
```

Так даже если возьмёшь лишние элементы, ошибки не возникнет

> ТС:
> нашел вот такую функцию:
> def penultimateBuiltin[A](ls: List[A]): A = if (ls.isEmpty) throw new NoSuchElementException else ls.init.last 
>
> но где тогда вписывать сам массив, которую она принимает?

метод `init` возвращает список со всеми элементами, кроме последнего.
Поэтому, вызов на нём `last` вернёт предпоследний элемент.
Такой подход тоже имеет место быть, но если нужно будет добираться до пред-предпоследнего, то цепочка будет расти.
Проще обращаться по индексу, то есть через скобки.
Рекомендую прочитать доку по спискам, в Скала для них много полезных методов уже имеется из под коробки:

https://scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Comment: а как тогда вернуть предпоследний элемент? это же отдельно уже функция пишется?

Comment: def penultimateBuiltin[A](ls: List[A]): A =
    if (ls.isEmpty) throw new NoSuchElementException
    else ls.init.last

нашел вот такую функцию, но где тогда вписывать сам массив, которую она принимает?

Comment: _а как тогда вернуть предпоследний элемент? это же отдельно уже функция пишется?_

`list(list.size - 2)`
вернёт предпоследний элемент. В скобочках обращение к конкретному элементу, то есть тут к элементу **размер списка - 2**

Comment: Можно вынести в отдельную функцию, где обработать на возможность ошибок, то есть например возвращать Option, если вдруг захочется получить -1 элемент списка.

Comment: Не знаю насколько корректно, но можно ещё поиграться с методом `take`:

`list.take(2).last // return 2 from list(1, 2, 3)`

Так даже если возьмёшь лишние элементы, ошибки не возникнет

Comment: спасибо! теперь понятнее)

Comment: Касательно твоего второго комментария, то метод `init` возвращает список со всеми элементами, кроме последнего. Поэтому, вызов на нём `last` вернёт предпоследний элемент. Такой подход тоже имеет место быть, но если нужно будет добираться до предпредпоследнего, то цепочка будет расти. Проще обращаться по индексу, то есть через скобки. Рекомендую прочитать доку по спискам, в Скала для них много полезных методов уже имеется из под коробки: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Comment: @dedkot, можете из комментариев все ответы и соображения в тело ответа самого перенести. А то он в очереди ответов с низким качеством находится. так и наминусовать могут. Хотя сам ответ корректный...Если перенесете - я вам плюсик влеплю)

Comment: @МихаилРебров хорошо, спасибо за замечание и редакцию!)

Comment: а если мы ищем k-й элемент в списке, тоже используем инит?

Comment: @КириллХолодченко Что имеешь ввиду под *k-й элемент в списке*?